# Character Encoding Issue with Django, Celery, and SendGrid

Tags: django, email, celery, sendgrid

I've been working with a setup that uses Django alongside Celery for dispatching emails, and we've integrated SendGrid for this purpose. However, I've come across a peculiar issue that I hope someone might shed some light on.

For some email templates, when sending out emails, characters with diacritics, specifically "ì", are being displayed as another character, in this case, "ě". I've double-checked and ensured that all software configurations are set to utf-8 encoding, but this inconsistency persists.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to debug or fix this?

Example:
"Martedě" instead of "Martedì"

[image]

Martedě" instead of "Martedì

The templates are saved in utf-8 encoding html files.
This is the code used to send emails:

```
message = render_to_string(
    "emails/booking_canceled/cliente_to_client.html",
    {
        "first_name": booking.customer_first_name,
        # ...
    },
)

email = EmailMessage(
    subject=subject,
    body=message,
    from_email=DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
    to=[booking.customer_email],
    headers={"Content-Type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"},
)
email.content_subtype = "html"
email.send()
logger.info(
    "[booking_code:  %s][customer_email: %s] Sent.",
    booking.code,
    booking.customer_email,
)
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance!